# Can I make the Bootstrap 4 navbar switch to a column instead of collapsing?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I would prefer that all my menu items remain visible at all times, and simply switch from a centered row formation into a centered column when the screen size is too small.

```
 <div style="position: sticky; top: 0px;">
```

```
    <!--<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar9">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>           
    </button>     this is the fricking collapse button -->

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">bbb</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ccc</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ddd</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">eee</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ffff</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show any relevant code so we can help you modify it, SO is not here to make a project from scratch for you.

Comment: I just did, thank you. Alternately, can you point me in the direction of a site where bootstrap attributes are listed and explained? Their own site doesn't have enough information that I could find, and I am a beginner at web design and reading CSS is very slow for me.

Comment: I'd recommend using vanilla CSS until you are very competent with it. Using a framework simply because you don't know how to create certain things will just make you dependent upon it.

Comment: bootstrap works from class, you can start to remove the collapse classes and see how it behaves. from there, dig into the class that boostrap has to build your layout as you wish. Here you need a column where content is centered and toggled from flex-row to flex-column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regular bootsrap class used to build your layout **and drop the collapsing navbar classes**: see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

> **Flex**
>
> Quickly manage the layout, alignment, and sizing of grid columns, navigation, components, and more with a full suite of responsive flexbox utilities. For more complex implementations, custom CSS may be necessary.

example with :`flex-md-row` class (play snippet in fullpage and resize windows to see it toggling row/column. You can try also `flex-lg-row` if you think it turns into column too late.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="navbar " id="navbar10">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 flex-md-row">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">bbb</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ccc</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ddd</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">eee</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ffff</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an elegant way to set a max distance between the menu items? So that they aren't spread across the entire screen when on a widescreen monitor?

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT. Just wrap the whole thing inside a div class="container"

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS *media queries*, you can set specific break-points to change your elements. In this example, if the window is *less than* 480px then we can adjust the width to 100%.

(To see it in action, click run > full page > then resize window)

```css
.navTitle {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightGrey;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .navTitle {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 1</p>
</div>

<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 2</p>
</div>

<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 3</p>
</div>

<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 4</p>
</div>

<div class="navTitle">
 <p>Section 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I might not actualy need bootstrap. I will try going it alone, but with Skeleton to help me make it pretty on little screens.

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend using vanilla CSS until you are well experienced with it.